# How to use local mvn project A in other mvn project B

Tags: dependencies, mvn-repo

I have put dependency of local mvn project in other project and jars are also showing in dependecies list as you can see below-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHRIt.png)

when I am trying use classes of common, I am able to see class but . It is showing error as below-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gm9G.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmEH6.png)

Comment: Did you `mvn install` the "common" project? Local projects have to be installed in your local repository (~/.m2/repository) to be visible to other projects

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.